# Azure Cloud Shell Ansible with Windows hosts

Tags: azure, pip, ansible, winrm, azure-cloud-shell

Since the [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/updates/ansible-now-available-in-bash-in-cloud-shell/) I'm able to list my Azure infrastructure in the Azure Cloud Shell with ansible.

I want to use it with Windows machines too. I installed the winrm locally as it seems that globally is not supported.

```
pip install "pywinrm>=0.2.2" --user
```

With this I understand packages are correctly installed

```
pywinrm (0.3.0)
requests (2.18.4)
xmltodict (0.11.0)
...
```

Then I run, with [the proper credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-install-configure#create-azure-credentials) a win ping but ansible complains that the WinRM is not available.

```
ansible -i workspace/azure_rm.py -m win_ping DC-01
```

[image: DC-01 | FAILED! => { "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named xmltodict" }]

Is it possible to run ansible in cloud shell with windows hosts?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your windows hosts are setup for WinRM control. That means you should check off a few things are working, you can see what Ansible has to say about it [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html#windows-system-prep).

- Network path is open on TCP port 5985-5986 (try to telnet)
- Powershell 3.0 or above is installed
- WinRM remoting has been configured for the remote windows host.
- Make sure the ansible play is using WinRM port to connect

You can use the excellent PS script ansible provides with a little modification if needed to setup your local certs and configure the box from [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1).

Comment: To me as per the issue message it looks like a missing library issue. I have other windows hosts running with Ansible already (using an ubuntu VM) and had no issue with them. My question was as I have not clear that the Cloud Shell supports WinRM management.

Comment: does ansible have a service on the windows hosts? What happens when it goes down ?

Comment: Ansible does not have a service on the Windows hosts, it operates mainly on WinRM and delivered powershell scripts to run the module commands.

Answer (score 0):

I finally opened [a post on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a659495b-8e77-481f-8691-11493f3125d8/azure-cloud-shell-ansible-with-windows-hosts?forum=windowsazuremanagement) and Microsoft identified the missing dependency and added in the Cloud Shell!

[image]

Finally it is possible to use Ansible from the Cloud Shell. The only consideration is that the target VM should have internet connectivity on port 5986.

Also there is [a sample script to test it](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks/blob/master/VMCreateWindows.yml).